# How to use Visual Studio 2013 to view the files of a Windows Azure Website?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-web-app-service

The [Troubleshooting Azure Web Sites in Visual Studio](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/#remoteview) tutorial indicates that I will be able to view Website files in Visual Studio. It says that I can "expand the node for the website that you're deploying to."

[image]

In my Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, though, there is no option to expand a website node.

[image]

How can I use Visual Studio to view the files of a Windows Azure Website?

Answer (score 1):

Can you double-check that you're running version 2.3 of the Azure SDK? My visual studio shows the files as intended with the newest Azure SDK.